# Apache mod_rewrite, redirect to an URL when a file with a particular extension is requested

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to use mod_rewrite to transform a URL like this one:

```
http://example.com/qxs/app/myapp.qxs
```

into

```
http://example.com/qxs/index.php?page=myapp
```

Currently I have this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^app/([^/\.]+).qxs /qxs/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But this ends up in an endless loop or something causing my PHP to report that the memory has exceeded and so on...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Morten

Comment: Where is you .htaccess file located?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `^/qxs/app...` in place of `^app...`?

Comment: should be moved to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^app/([^/.]+)\.qxs$ qxs/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I was hoping for a quick answer but this was just insane!
Worked like a charm! I just had to remove the ^app/ part and use an URL without this directory to make your rule work!
But thank you! Solved!

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is complaining then your RewriteRule has hit the server and the problem probably lies in the PHP code.